# does not contain a definition for " " and no extension method accepting a first argument

Tags: c#

```
i am having trouble with my set and gets in my test class. it says it does not
```

contain a definition for ______ and no extension method accepting a first argument. i have read similar problems but i can not fix these errors. how can i fix this? Specifically it says my Car class does not contain a definition

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Homework1 
{
    class Car
    {
        private string color;
        private int numOfWheels;
        private int startingPoint;
        private int mileage;
        private int currentSpeed;

        public Car()
        {
            color = "";
            NumOfWheels = 4;
            StartingPoint = 100000;
            CurrentSpeed = 0;
            Mileage = 0;
        }

        public Car(string color, int numOfWheels, int startingPoint, int currentSpeed, int mileage)
        {
            Color = color;
            NumOfWheels = numOfWheels;
            StartingPoint = startingPoint;
            CurrentSpeed = currentSpeed;
            Mileage = mileage;
        }

        public virtual string Color
        {
            get
            {
                return color;
            }
            set
            {
                color = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual int NumOfWheels
        {
            get
            {
                return numOfWheels;
            }
            set
            {
                numOfWheels = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual int StartingPoint
        {
            get
            {
                return startingPoint;
            }
            set
            {
                startingPoint = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual int CurrentSpeed
        {
            get
            {
                return currentSpeed;
            }
            set
            {
                currentSpeed = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual int Mileage
        {
            get
            {
                return mileage;
            }
            set
            {
                mileage = value;
            } 
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return (" color " + color + " numOfWheels" + numOfWheels + "startingPoint " + startingPoint + "mileage" + mileage + "current speed" + currentSpeed);
        }
     }
}

********************************************************************************
///this is the test program

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Homework1
{
    class CarTest
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Car myCar = new Car();


                Console.WriteLine("*****************************"); 
                Console.WriteLine("*                           *"); 
                Console.WriteLine("*  WELCOME TO CAR MANAGER   *");
                Console.WriteLine("*    By <<my Name>>         *"); 
                Console.WriteLine("*                           *");
                Console.WriteLine("*****************************");



            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the number of wheels of a car");
            int numOfWheels = Console.Read();
            myCar.setNumOfWheels(numOfWheels);



            Console.WriteLine("Enter the color of the car");
            String color = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Current mileage will be set to zero");

            Console.WriteLine("The current starting point will be set to 100000");

            Console.Write("The current status of your car \n{0:D} Wheels, \n{1}, \n{2:D} Miles and \nCAR POINT = {3:D}", myCar.getNumOfWheels, 
            myCar.getColor, myCar.getMileage, myCar.getStartingPoint);

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the owner's name");
            String name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the miles the car ran in this week");
            int milesThisWeek = Console.ReadLine();
            myCar.setMileage(Mileage);

            Console.WriteLine("This car is owned by n{1}", name); 


                Console.WriteLine("===>The current status of your car:");
            Console.WriteLine("Wheels: " + myCar.getWheels());
            Console.WriteLine("Color: " + myCar.getColor());
                Console.WriteLine("Current Mileage: " + myCar.getMileage());
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Point: " + myCar.getStartingPoint());
            Console.WriteLine("************ Thank you for using CAR MANAGER *************");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close console…….");    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you omit the most relevant info from the error message?

Comment: also noticed you are using the following
Console.WriteLine("This car is owned by n{1}", name); 
index should always start at 0

Answer (score 2):

In your Car class, you have this property (among others):

```
    public virtual int NumOfWheels
    {
        get
        {
            return numOfWheels;
        }
        set
        {
            numOfWheels = value;
        }
    }
```

and you attempt to use it like this:

```
myCar.setNumOfWheels(numOfWheels);
```

`setNumOfWheels()` doesn't exist. You instead need to use property syntax to use `NumOfWheels`,

```
myCar.NumOfWheels = 4; // sets the property 
Console.WriteLine(myCar.NumOfWheels); // gets the property
```

See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

---

As an aside, there's nothing stopping you from using auto property syntax for your properties. As they are, they do nothing beyond access the value behind the scenes. So you can, omitting the explicit private variable, just declare `NumOfWheels` like this:

```
public virtual int NumOfWheels { get; set; }
```

and get the same behavior you have now.